# Cython 0.23.4 AttributeError when .pyx and .pxd files in subdirectory

Tags: cython, subdirectory, attributeerror

I upgraded my Cython to version 0.23.4 and my code now leads to an AttributeError when I put the .pyx and .pxd files in subdirectories of my working directory.
The minimal example containing the error is as follows:

Main python file in working directory:

```
import pyximport;
import os,sys; 
pyximport.install()
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+'/pxd')
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+'/pyx')
from X import *

xObj = X(5)
```

pyx/X.pyx (i.e. in subdirectory pyx/):

```
cdef class X:
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.var = var
```

pxd/X.pxd (i.e. in subdirectory pxd/):

```
cdef class X:
    cdef public int var
```

Running Main.py gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'X.X' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Note, the code runs fine if I move the X.pyx and X.pxd files into my working directory. But this is very inconvenient due to a large number of files.

What can I do to get the code running, whilst having the X.pyx and X.pxd in the subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython expects the .pyx and .pxd files to be in the same directory as each other, (which doesn't have to be your working directory). As it currently stands I think you're importing only "`X.pyx`", and it isn't realising that "`X.pxd`" is related to it.

Therefore you could create a directory called "`cython_files`" (to keep your files out of your working directory), and in that directory you'd put both "`X.pxd`" and "`X.pyx`". You could then add "cython_files" to your path, and you wouldn't get any attribute errors.

Better yet, you could add an "`__init__.py`" to your "`cython_files`" directory and then it's treated as a Python module and you can do `from cython_files.X import X`, and not have to add anything to your path.

*Edit for clarity:* @romenic's answer identifies the same issue, but suggests a slightly different solution to it (which I suspect works) - this answer argues that OP really shouldn't organize their files in the way they do, rather than trying to work round it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Cython cannot find your header files (`.pxd`) if you split them into different directories, unless you explicitly import the declarations

```
from pxd_file cimport class_declaration
```

assuming that the path to `pxd_file` is visible to the compiler. In the case of example you have given this simply translates to

```
from X cimport X
```

Have a look at these Cython's [internal examples](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/b476c360bff59f8fa868ffd03f107ac1664e4a6f/tests/run/includes/all.pyx).

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the AttributeError. My test code ran perfectly before the Cython upgrade. So I think the problem must be in the generated .c files.

Comment: The working example that you have posted runs without any warning on my machine, with what I have proposed and I am using Cython 0.23.4. It is hard to guess what is the problem in your actual code. Perhaps you can delete the `.c` files and re-compile the whole thing. That should fix the issue. If not then you can always report a bug on the Cython mailing list if you feel this is an issue with 0.23.4 version.